# Uncaught error when attempting to close popup using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup, initialization

I'm using jquerymobile (1.4.0). I have a single html file which calls a javascript function that creates a reset popup. The reset popup has two buttons (yes, no), which, in both cases should close the popup after performing some other operations.

When the close button is pressed, I receive the following error:

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on popup prior to initialization;
>   attempted to call method 'close'

From searching stackoverflow and other sites I could see suggestions that I should call ("mypopup").popup() prior to my close operation, which I'm doing. I have tried calling ("#theResetPopup") as well as ("#lnkResetPopup") but neither of these work. Calling $(this).popup.close(); (after ( $this.popup() ) from the 'no' button only results in causing the actual button to disappear.

If I do the following within the btnResetNo handler

```
$("#theResetPopup").popup();
$("#theResetPopup").popup("close");
```

the popup does disappear but I receive the following error:

> Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on
>   'Node': The new child element contains the parent.

I think the issue is to do with the fact that I'm using the lnkPopup method but I'm at a loss as to how to fix it. :(

Any help is very much appreciated, thanks in advance!

From my .html file.

```
<a id='lnkResetPopup' href="#theResetPopup" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="flip" data-role="popup" data-position-to="window" style='display:none;'></a>

<div data-role="page" id="theResetPopup" data-role="popup">   
    <div data-role="header" id="resetPopupTitle">
        Reset
    </div>  

    All progress will be lost. Are you sure?

    <center>
    <button id="btnResetYes" type="submit" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-notext">Yes</button>
    <button id="btnResetNo" type="submit" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext">No</button>
    </center>

    <script>
    $( "#btnResetYes" ).click(function() {
        gameClass.resetGame();  
        gameClass.closeResetPopup();
    });

    $( "#btnResetNo" ).click(function() {
        gameClass.closeResetPopup();
        //$("#theResetPopup").popup();
        //$("#theResetPopup").popup("close");
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

From my JavaScript file.

```
showResetPopup:function()
{
    $("#lnkResetPopup").popup();
    $("#lnkResetPopup").popup('open');

    $("#resetPopupTitle").html('<center>Reset?</center>');
},

closeResetPopup:function()
{
    $("#lnkResetPopup").popup();
    $("#lnkResetPopup").popup('close');
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing dialog and popup markup.

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Gdfp2/1/)**

The link takes a data-rel of popup, while the popup div loses the page role and takes the data-position-to:

```
<div data-role="page" id="my_view">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>My page</h1> 
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content"> 

        <a id="lnkResetPopup" href="#theResetPopup" data-transition="flip" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn">Reset </a>

    </div>

    <div id="theResetPopup" data-role="popup" data-position-to="window" data-dismissible="false">
        <div data-role="header" id="resetPopupTitle">Reset</div>All progress will be lost. Are you sure?
        <center>
            <button id="btnResetYes" type="submit" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-notext">Yes</button>
            <button id="btnResetNo" type="submit" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext">No</button>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

To close from code, you then just call `$("#theResetPopup").popup('close');` I also take the code out of the markup and put it in bottom of the page with all the other javascript.

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnResetYes", function () {
    $("#theResetPopup").popup('close');
});
$(document).on("click", "#btnResetNo", function () {
    $("#theResetPopup").popup('close');
});
```

Comment: Hi ezanker. Thanks for taking the time to answer this, for solving the issue and for the fiddle :) I really appreciate it. I can't vote up your answer as I have no reputation as yet but I've 'accepted' it. If there's something else I need to do to give you credit for the answer, please let me know.

Comment: Accepting the answer is plenty. I'm glad I could be of help.